# Getting 'ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[-0.27861589].' in python for predicting SVR regrssion

Tags: python, valueerror

I am having trouble to solve the array dimension problem showing in the code. When I am trying to figure out the y_predict, the valueerror problem is showing. here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#importing dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Position_Salaries.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,1:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,2].values
y=np.reshape(y,(10,1))

#Spliting dataset into training set and test set
'''from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state = 0)'''

#Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

######## SVR regression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr_regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf')   #rbf = gaussian kernel
svr_regressor.fit(X, y)

#Prediction of given value using SVR regression
X = np.reshape(X,(-1, 1))
y_predict = sc_y.inverse_transform(svr_regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))

########### Visulization of svr model
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'blue')
plt.plot(X, svr_regressor.predict(X), color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

I am getting error:
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-0.27861589].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Could you please paste your full traceback, showing the line at which the Exception was raised?

Comment: Support Vector Regression (SVR)\svr_mine.py", line 36, in <module>
    y_predict = sc_y.inverse_transform(svr_regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))

  File "G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 1017, in inverse_transform
    X = check_array(

  File "G:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 879, in check_array
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[-0.27861589].

Answer (score 0):

A little late but here i go in case someone might need it in the future, so
the problem comes in the `inverse_transform` function near the end

`y_predict = sc_y.inverse_transform(svr_regressor.predict(sc_X.transform([[6.5]])))`

This function only takes 2D array-like data, i.e., of shape (n_samples,n_features) as it's argument, but the argument you are passing is the result of the `predict` function from the `SVR` object, according to the [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.predict) this will return an array of shape (n_samples,), meaning, a 1D array, that is what raises the valueError

In order to solve this you have to shape the result of the `predict` function into a 2D array, it would look something like this:

```
    reg = regressor.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]])))
    reg = np.reshape(reg,(-1,1))
    sc_Y.inverse_transform(reg)
```